# Uri Compare To Handle Opposite Slash

Tags: c#, .net, uri, normalization

I have an automated process which generates localized Uri's and then compares them to a list gathered from a remote source in the cloud. When one uses `Uri.Compare` on the paths, if one of the paths contains a different facing slash (either `/` vs `\`) it reports a `1` instead of `O`.

Such as a compare of `/sites/OmegaSandbox\Shared Documents` versus `/sites/OmegaSandbox/Shared Documents`.

How can one *normalize* the uri effectively, or to adjust the `Compare` method to handle the different slash situation **using existing tools in `.Net`**?

**Supposition**

```
Path.Combine("/sites/OmegaSandbox", "Shared Documents")
```

will generate this string

> /sites/OmegaSandbox\Shared Documents

which is the start of the issue.

*An ancillary question might be how to get Path.Combine to respect the left hand input slash direction?*

Now at this point, sure one could write a regex replace operation such as `Regex.Replace(" ... ", @"(\\)", "/")` to swap out the slashes and that is what I might have to do.

But the StackOverflow beast must be fed and this question is red meat right?

**Example**

```
string uri1 = Path.Combine("/sites/OmegaSandbox", "Shared Documents");
string uri2 = @"/sites/OmegaSandbox/Shared Documents";

var u1 = new Uri(uri1, UriKind.Relative);
var u2 = new Uri(uri2, UriKind.Relative);

Uri.Compare(u1, u2, UriComponents.Fragment, 
                    UriFormat.SafeUnescaped, 
                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

The `Uri.Compare` above regardless of what attributes are set, will never return a `0`.

---

Is there any out of the box way to get the `Compare` or `Combine` to work with differing slashes?

Comment: Changing `Shared Documents` to `SharedDocuments` (no space) has the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding an extension method with custom compare logic like

```
public static class UriExtension
{
    public static bool EqualityCheck(this Uri uri, Uri anotherUri)
    {
        return uri.OriginalString.Replace(@"\", @"/").Equals(anotherUri.OriginalString.Replace(@"\", @"/"));
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
var u1 = new Uri(uri1, UriKind.Relative);
var u2 = new Uri(uri2, UriKind.Relative);

u1.EqualityCheck(u2);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but  my intent is to find out if the `Uri` or `Compare` method could be adjusted to do that normalization out of the box. Thanks though for trying. +1 for the try. :-)

Comment: The Remarks section in [Uri.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation says it clearly that if both the URLs are relative it will use standard String.Compare(String, String, StringComparison) method for comparison

Comment: Ugg, this is like buying a car and you are telling me to read the fine print. lol. Good find...but if it is not a fragment...does that change things I wonder.